# xcode 6 with iPhone5(8.0) simulator - when i run the project Showing Clang error

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Previously i worked on one project that is executing fine in **Xcode 5.1.1** version. When i run the same code in **Xcode 6** with **iPhone5(8.0) simulator** it is showing clang error. Here i am adding that error. please help me out.

```
 Ld /Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EuroTrips.app/EuroTrips normal i386
        cd /Users/Anji/ios-trip-europe
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.0
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Anji/ios-trip-europe/EuroTrips/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries\ &\ Headers -F/Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Intermediates/EuroTrips.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EuroTrips.build/Objects-normal/i386/EuroTrips.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -framework Social -weak-lxml2 -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Twitter -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -lsqlite3.0 -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Intermediates/EuroTrips.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EuroTrips.build/Objects-normal/i386/EuroTrips_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Anji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EuroTrips-cqammgactoqvmbdefwhycdhgrfkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EuroTrips.app/EuroTrips

    ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: may i know why down vote?

Comment: Your deployment target is set to 4.0 but `-pie` can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later as clearly stated by the above error message. Try setting your deployment target to 4.3. This is the lowest deployment target supported by Xcode 6.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the complete error as code so others can find your post by searching SO.

Comment: Also, don't use code formatting for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

Your deployment target is set to 4.0 but -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later as clearly stated by the above error message. Try setting your deployment target to 4.3. This is the lowest deployment target supported by Xcode 6.